# How can I configure swagger-ui to emit camelcase json variables instead of underscores when using with ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack

I am using ServiceStack.Api.Swagger. Everything is working and I can see my api docs fine. I have configured ServiceStack to emit camel case name `JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;` and ServiceStack is emitting the variables as expected (e.g trainStation). However when I view the Request/Response schemas in my swagger output/screen, all of the variables that ServiceStack emits as camel case are displayed with an underscore separator (e.g. train-station). Is there a way to configure swagger-ui to emit camel case instead of underscores? Or, configure ServiceStack and swagger-ui to be consistent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are properties on the `SwaggerFeature` class. In your AppHost, after configuring JsConfig:

```
Plugins.Add(new SwaggerFeature {
    UseCamelCaseModelPropertyNames = JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames
});
```